# Salesforce Rest API/SOQL can't get picklist values from a custom object

Tags: salesforce, soql, salesforce-rest-api

I'm able to get the picklist values from the standard object (e.g: Contact, Account), but when I use the same way to a **custom** object (Event), it always return 0 result. Need the help to get the some picklist values from the event.
[image]
[image]

Note: I need ALL values available from a picklist field in the object. Example: all country list under Country__c (which is a picklist type) in the event.

The ways I tried:

way 1: directly write SOQL to get the info
SELECT Label,Value FROM PicklistValueInfo WHERE EntityParticle.EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName = 'APINameOfObject' AND EntityParticle.QualifiedApiName = 'APINameOfField' and isActive = true LIMIT 1000

Way 2: make an REST API to get describe info back
https://my.salesforce.com/services/data/v44.0/sobjects/Contact/describe
(can see each picklist description with all values listed for Contact)
https://my.salesforce.com/services/data/v44.0/sobjects/Event/describe
(can't get the picklist name/values return even I could see it in the Salesforce portal)

Way 3: SOQL to get label, value, DurableId info fro EntityDefinition and PicklistValueInfo
Way 4: SOQL in the API
https://{domainurl}.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v44.0/query/?q=SELECT Id, Label, Value,DurableId from PicklistValueInfo WHERE EntityParticleId = 'Account.Industry'

I asked my Salesforce Admin and confirmed there is no such way to "block" the picklist values return, the custom object should behave as same as the stand ones.

Thanks so much to read through my question!

Comment: Event is standard, not custom. You mean the standard object or you have your own custom Event__c? Is the picklist marked as "global" (defined in another place in setup and reused / kept in sync across several objects? Standard Task/Event is special, check if your REST describe returns something if you pass "Activity" object type.

Comment: as you mention in your example with country list (ie, Country__c), try Country__r.Name, so basically FieldName__r.Name in your SOQL

Comment: Hello again eyescream...I attached the screen shot above (in my original post) so u can see that Event__c is a custom object. 
I compared two picklist field under Account and Event in the setting page, can't find the picklist defined as global or any other scope in the definition detail.
I did find a button "set field-level security" and checked 3 API related fields as visible but it doesn't help.

Comment: Hi smoore4, I believe use Country__c or __r will bring back only the selected value for a particular event, not all available values.

Answer (score 1):

Updates:
for the custom object, I need to use `Event__c` instead of `Event`, so the working soql is:

```
SELECT Label,Value FROM PicklistValueInfo WHERE EntityParticle.EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName = '**Event__c**' AND EntityParticle.QualifiedApiName = 'Country__c' and isActive = true LIMIT 1000
```

earlier I used: `QualifiedApiName = '**Event**'` which doesn't work, `Account` is a standard object that's why it works.